# Getting Azure key vault certificates works only from local machine

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, identityserver4, azure-keyvault

I am using Identity server to handle logins in my app hosted in MS Azure. I am using Azure key vault to store my certificates. When I am trying to obtain certificates from Azure Key Vault on local machine, everything works fine, but after deploying to the server, I am getting the error described bellow.

I have followed this tutorial: https://damienbod.com/2020/04/09/using-certificates-from-azure-key-vault-in-asp-net-core/

I have created Azure AD and registered my app into it. Also I have created Azure Key Vault, added my app into Key Vault access principles and inside my app service I have allowed identity assigned by the system.

[image]

When I deployed this app on the server I am getting this error
[image]

In the key vault I allowed all permissions for this app
[image]

Is there some more setting, which needs to be done before deploying?

Thanks.

Comment: Have configured access policy for Azure MSI in your key vault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you enable the system-assigned identity for your app service, you also need to add it to the `Access policies` of the keyvault with the correct certificate permission(just navigate to the `Access policies`, search for the web app name and add it).

The sample you provided use the `AzureServiceTokenProvider`, when you deploy your code to app service, it should use the system-assigned identity to access the keyvault in your case.

To let this work, you also need to specify the `AzureServicesAuthConnectionString` environment variable in your app service with `RunAs=App`, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/service-to-service-authentication#connection-string-support).

[image]